# Add images in column

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image, animation

Pleas help.What is the best way to organize some images in column,to have easy way calculate animation of img adding,depending on how many pictures are already added.
Picture - http://bit.ly/OBK8xk
Thanks a lot.Sorry for bad English.

Comment: nothing,but alredy done with help rehan.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using for loop.for eg.The dynamic images can be achieved by fetching it in an array(imagearray).Then try this code

```
static int statvar = 0;
for(int i=0;i<[imagearray count];i++)
{
    UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10+statvar, 50, 50)];
    [imgView  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]]
    statvar+=55;
    [self.view addsubview:imgView];
}
```